# Set ngModel sub-property dynamically

Tags: angular, ngfor, ngmodel

I need to set a ngModel sub-property dynamically like this inside an ngFor.

```
<div *ngFor="let weekday of this.weekdays">
  <mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="openingHoursObj.[weekday].isOpen">Open</mat-slide-toggle>
</div>
```

... where weekday can be monday, tuesday, wednesday etc.

It says: Property weekday does not exist on OpeningHoursViewModel.

How can you go about setting this sub-property dynamically in similar fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `this.` from `this.weekdays` and removing the first `.` from `openingHoursObj.[weekday].isOpen`. That will access the class property and object properties correctly, respectively.

Result:

```
<div *ngFor="let weekday of weekdays">
  <mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="openingHoursObj[weekday].isOpen">Open</mat-slide-toggle>
</div>
```